# Uniquness of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ in the equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me to solve the following problem:

I got differential equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$. It is know that his solutions are:

1. $\sin x$
2. $\sin x, \cos x$
3. $\sin x, 2 \sin x$

For every case determine if $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are uniquely determined.

My attempt:

I think that cases 1 and 3 are the same since the equation is homogenous. What I did next is plugged every set of functions into the equation and tried to see if  $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are uniquely determined. In case $1$ I got $$-\sin x + p(x)\cos x + q(x) \sin x = 0.$$ I do think the answer is not-unique. In case $2$ I got additional equation $$-\cos x - p(x)\sin x + q(x) \cos x = 0.$$ It looks like now we got linear system and the solution is unique : $p(x)=0$ and $q(x)=1$.

Can you please check my solution and correct it if it is wrong!

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Update:
As $A.Γ.$ mentioned the explanation was poor. Now, using his hints I will try to improve:

1. Using arbitrary function $\phi(x)$ it is possible to construct arbitrary $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ such that equation holds, so they are not unique.

$$
p(x)=\phi(x)\sin x,\quad q(x)-1=-\phi(x)\cos x
$$

2. Consider linear system:
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos x & \sin x\\-\sin x & \cos x
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix}
   p(x)\\q(x)
   \end{bmatrix}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \sin x\\ \cos x
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   Appling the Cramer's rule we get that $p(x)=0$ and $q(x)=1$, i.e. they are unique and do not depend on $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guess is correct, the explanation is scanty.

Case 1 and 3: consider
$$
p(x)=\phi(x)\sin x,\quad q(x)-1=-\phi(x)\cos x
$$
and explain why there are many $p,q$.

Case 2: consider the system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos x & \sin x\\-\sin x & \cos x
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p(x)\\q(x)-1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and explain why the solution is unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. I've updated my answer, is it ok now?

Comment: @Hedgehog Yes, it is good now. Maybe better to say "the determinant is nonzero" in the case 2, it is all you need for uniqueness.

Comment: Yes, it is much better, of course, thanks.